# tikz: How to draw nested ellipses which contain bent text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw nested ellipses, where each ellipse shows some text
(``Function 1'',...,''Function 4'' to visualize dependence of function
calls). I'd like to have the text bent according to the corresponding
ellipse. The following is a first trial (not sure if it's a good approach to get
to this picture). When I compile it (TeXLive 2012 on Ubuntu 12.10), it
hangs... what's wrong? Or rather: What's a good way to draw this picture?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=zigzag]
  % ellipses
  \filldraw[fill=gray!10, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (6.4cm and 3.2cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!20, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (4.8cm and 2.4cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!30, draw=gray!80,
            postaction={decorate,
                        decoration={text along path, text={\texttt{Function
                              2}}}}] (0,0) ellipse (3.2cm and 1.6cm);% TODO:
                                % place the text on top of "Function 1"
  \filldraw[fill=gray!40, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (1.6cm and 0.8cm) node
  {\texttt{Function 1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `\texttt` around 'Function 2' causes LaTeX to hang. Just don't know why... If you remove it, the code will compile just fine.

Comment: @CountZero The `text along path` arranges its text letter by letter. The `\texttt` macro groups the text and TikZ can’t split it right. You can use `|\ttfamily| …`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract from [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf):

> Within the decoration `text along path`, each character in the text is
>   typeset in a separate `\hbox`. [...] It is possible to format the text
>   using normal formatting commands, such as \it, \bf and \color, within
>   **customizable delimiters**.  Initially these delimiters are both `|`

(emphasis added).

So, in your text, use `|\tt|...` instead of `\texttt{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=zigzag]
  % ellipses
  \filldraw[fill=gray!10, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (6.4cm and 3.2cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!20, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (4.8cm and 2.4cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!30, draw=gray!80,
  postaction={decorate,
    decoration={text along path,
      text={|\tt|Function 2},
    },
  }] (0,0) ellipse (3.2cm and 1.6cm);% TODO:
                                % place the text on top of "Function 1"
  \filldraw[fill=gray!40, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (1.6cm and 0.8cm) node
  {\texttt{Function 1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1 min faster than me... `:)`

Comment: @CountZero As I struggle to write rapidly in English, I cheat: I copy  the documentation. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is a follow-up here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96551/tikz-how-to-mirror-the-path-decoration-text-along-path