# tikz: How to mirror the path decoration "text along path"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to create labeled nested ellipses in tikz. The labels should follow the
shape of the ellipses. I used a path decoration with `pre` to move the label to
the right place, but I couldn't figure out: a): how to turn it [the `mirror`
option mirrors it in the wrong way] and b): as soon as I include `pre` and `pre
length`, other options (such as `raise` or `mirror`) do not seem to be respected
anymore. Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=zigzag]
  % ellipses
  \filldraw[fill=gray!10, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (6.4cm and 3.2cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!20, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (4.8cm and 2.4cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!30, draw=gray!80,
            postaction={decorate,
                        decoration={pre=moveto, pre length=3cm, raise=4mm, text along path, text={|\tt|Function 2}}}]
           (0,0) ellipse (3.2cm and 1.6cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!40, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (1.6cm and 0.8cm) node
  {\texttt{Function 1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Re: the `raise` not working with `pre`: just experienced this, and it seems it has been reported as bug, and fixed in 2013: [PGF and TikZ -- Graphic systems for TeX / Bugs / #116 Decorations can't be repositioned when pre/post used](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/116/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of decorate the ellipse, you can decorate an arc of this ellipse. And you can choose the direction of this arc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=zigzag]
  % ellipses
  \filldraw[fill=gray!10, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (6.4cm and 3.2cm);
  \path[postaction={decorate,
    decoration={
      raise=-1em,
      text along path,
      text={|\tt|Function 4},
      text align=center,
    },
  }] (0,0) ++(110:6.4cm and 3.2cm) arc(110:70:6.4cm and 3.2cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!20, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (4.8cm and 2.4cm);
  \path[postaction={decorate,
    decoration={
      raise=-1em,
      text along path,
      text={|\tt|Function 3},
      text align=center,
    },
  }] (0,0) ++(110:4.8cm and 2.4cm) arc(110:70:4.8cm and 2.4cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!30, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (3.2cm and 1.6cm);
  \path[postaction={decorate,
    decoration={
      raise=-1em,
      text along path,
      text={|\tt|Function 2},
      text align=center,
    },
  }] (0,0) ++(110:3.2cm and 1.6cm) arc(110:70:3.2cm and 1.6cm);
  \filldraw[fill=gray!40, draw=gray!80] (0,0) ellipse (1.6cm and 0.8cm) node
  {\texttt{Function 1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you really want to, you can mirror the text with `reverse path`, or add space before the text with `text align={left indent=<insert favorite length>}`, but this answer is a much easier and more elegant way of doing it.