# shortening of braces (or padding tikz brace decorations)

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Feels a bit weird doing this, but I found this unanswered question: [PGF and TikZ (mailing list) - shortening of braces](http://pgf-and-tikz.10981.n7.nabble.com/shortening-of-braces-td4651.html), and as I'm interested in the answer, I'll repost:

> many times i need to give some description to groups of successive
>   (rectangle) shapes, i.e. something like this: [below]
>   where i like to have small space between successive braces without
>   changing braces coordinates. so i try to use shorten, but result is only
>   partly satisfactory... (see braces C and D). well, if i set shorten to
>   0.5 points, braces look perfectly, but distance between them is little
>   to small.
>
> do anyone has better solution?

Here is the output of the example:

[image: test41]

I have added the red brace as an example of a preferred solution (for me), where it has 1 pt "padding"; the `shorten`ed braces are below it, and they don't look that good. The red brace looks OK, but it is achieved with `calc` and manually offsetting the end points, which for me is somewhat tedious to type.

So, is there a better way of achieving a "shortened" or "padded" brace?

Here is the MWE (with the red brace modification):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, minimum size=9pt,inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt, right},
brc/.style = {decorate, decoration={brace,raise=1mm}},
shorten <>/.style = {shorten >=#1pt, shorten <=#1pt}
                     ]
\coordinate (a0) at (0,0);
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,4}
   \node[box] (a\x) at (a\xi.east) {\x};
\draw[brc] (a1.north west) to node[above=2mm] {A} (a2.north east);
\draw[brc] (a3.north west) to node[above=2mm] {B} (a4.north east);
\def\brcpad{1pt}
\draw[brc, draw=red, decoration={raise=0.5mm}] ($(a2.south east)+(-\brcpad,0pt)$) -- ($(a1.south west)+(\brcpad,0pt)$);
\draw[brc,shorten <>=1] (a2.south east) to node[below=2mm] {C} (a1.south
west);
\draw[brc,shorten <>=1] (a4.south east) to node[below=2mm] {D} (a3.south
west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @sdauu Thank you to ask again this question. and I liked, actually I will use your (second) answer in similar cases in future.

Answer (score 4):

Got it - but it's tricky, because a bug is hit; it has been noted in [tikz: How to mirror the path decoration "text along path"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96551/tikz-how-to-mirror-the-path-decoration-text-along-path):

> b): as soon as I include `pre` and `pre length`, other options (such as `raise` or `mirror`) do not seem to be respected anymore.

This is actually [PGF and TikZ -- Graphic systems for TeX / Bugs / #116 Decorations can't be repositioned when pre/post used](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/116/). Having seen in online searches that the `raise` code is in  `tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex`, I managed to track down the diff of the fix for bug #116:

- [SourceForge.net Repository - [pgf] Diff of /pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex r1=1.14 & r2=1.15](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex?r1=1.14&r2=1.15)

Otherwise, the answer is - one can use `pre`/`post` (and their `length`) to "shorten" the brace decoration; so in the below MWE, there is a `brcb` style, which specifies the "padding" of 1 pt via `pre length` and `post length`; and outputs the following image:

[image: test42.png]

(the `brcb` style is applied to the "D" brace; it is raised at 0.5mm so as to compare it with the red brace)

Here is the code - including the pasted bugfix:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% copied fix for [http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/116/ PGF and TikZ -- Graphic systems for TeX / Bugs / #116 Decorations can't be repositioned when pre/post used]
% http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex?r1=1.14&r2=1.15
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{tikz@internal}{pre}{
  \state{pre}[width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/pre length}, next state=main]
  {
    \tikz@dec@trans
    \decoration{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/pre}}
  }
  \state{main}[width=\pgfmetadecoratedremainingdistance-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/post length}, next state=final]
  {
    \tikz@dec@trans
    \decoration{\tikz@decoration@name}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \tikz@dec@trans
    \decoration{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/post}}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, minimum size=9pt,inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt, right},
brc/.style = {decorate, decoration={brace,raise=1mm}},
brcb/.style = {decoration={brace,pre=moveto,pre length=1pt,post=moveto,post length=1pt,raise=0.5mm}, decorate},
shorten <>/.style = {shorten >=#1pt, shorten <=#1pt}
]
\coordinate (a0) at (0,0);
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,4}
   \node[box] (a\x) at (a\xi.east) {\x};
\draw[brc] (a1.north west) to node[above=2mm] {A} (a2.north east);
\draw[brc] (a3.north west) to node[above=2mm] {B} (a4.north east);
\def\brcpad{1pt}
\draw[brc, draw=red, decoration={raise=0.5mm}] ($(a2.south east)+(-\brcpad,0pt)$) -- ($(a1.south west)+(\brcpad,0pt)$);
\draw[brc,shorten <>=1] (a2.south east) to node[below=2mm] {C} (a1.south
west);
\draw[brcb] (a4.south east) to node[below=2mm] {D} (a3.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not a `tikz` person, so I apologize if my syntax is flawed, but here I provide `\downbrace[max.-height]{width}` and `\upbrace[max.-height]{width}`.  The syntax is relatively straightforward to write, but the dimensions must be explicitly specified.  While for some things that could be tough, here you specified your boxes as 9pt on edge, and so the brace span would be 2x9pt - 2pt buffer = 16pt long.  I show them in blue, for this MWE.  And I also use two different max.-heights, again for illustration.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\downbrace[2][1ex]{\textcolor{blue}{\rotatebox{90}{\scaleto[#1]{\}}{#2}}}}
\newcommand\upbrace[2][1ex]{\textcolor{blue}{\rotatebox{90}{\scaleto[#1]{\{}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, minimum size=9pt,inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt, right},
brc/.style = {decorate, decoration={brace,raise=1mm}},
shorten <>/.style = {shorten >=#1pt, shorten <=#1pt}
                     ]
\coordinate (a0) at (0,0);
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,4}
   \node[box] (a\x) at (a\xi.east) {\x};
\draw[brc] (a1.north west) to node[above=2mm] {A} (a2.north east);
\draw[brc] (a3.north west) to node[above=2mm] {B} (a4.north east);
\def\brcpad{1pt}
\draw[brc, draw=red, decoration={raise=0.5mm}] ($(a2.south east)+(-\brcpad,0pt)$) -- ($(a1.south west)+(\brcpad,0pt)$);
\draw (a1.north west) to node[above=-1.1mm] {\downbrace{16pt}} (a2.north east);
\draw (a3.south west) to node[below=-1mm] {\upbrace[.9ex]{16pt}} (a4.south east);
\draw[brc,shorten <>=1] (a2.south east) to node[below=2mm] {C} (a1.south
west);
\draw[brc,shorten <>=1] (a4.south east) to node[below=2mm] {D} (a3.south
west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @StevenBSegletes - that is a very interesting solution! I was kinda hoping for a tikz style though... Still - good to have this documented - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Understood.  I should add that the optional height argument is the "maximum height".  If the natural height is less than this value, it will leave the underlying brace shape alone.